# remove the specified nodes and their children

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML like this.

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <e>
      </e>
    </c>
    <d>
    </d>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>
      <e>
      <e>
    </c>
    <d>
    </d>
  </b>
</a>
```

And I need to copy the whole document and remove all the `<c>` elements and their children. After that I want to store the new document into variable.

Here is the XML I want to have after transformation:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <d>
    </d>
  </b>
  <b>
    <d>
    </d>
  </b>
</a>
```

And what I currently have:

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="c"/>
```

Comment: If that is the whole of your stylesheet then it should already do what you're asking for.  Can you show more of your stylesheet and the output you're _currently_ getting (not just the output you _want_), and explain how it is different from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see that are wrong:

- Your input is missing a closing tag for your second `<e>` element
- Your xslt script is missing the header

So, change your input to something well formed like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <e>
      </e>
    </c>
    <d>
    </d>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>
      <e>
      </e>
    </c>
    <d>
    </d>
  </b>
</a>
```

Add header and xsl:stylesheet tag around your stylesheet like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="c"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the whole thing works, producing an output like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
  <b>
    <d>
    </d>
  </b>
  <b>
    <d>
    </d>
  </b>
</a>
```

Comment: This is the example. So i have a header and well formed document. It's not working for me.

Comment: Of course this is the (fixed) example. More you did not give for information. However all of this I tested on an online XSLT tester (just paste xml + xslt script to one of them e.g http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html or http://xslttest.appspot.com/ ) and check the results. If you get an error, post it. If you are using some library, say which and you might get help on that. But what you have posted, there is only those two issues.